# Video textures in Three.js with Google Cardboard

Tags: javascript, three.js, html5-video, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I want to implement a video texture in Three.js following the method used in this example: http://stemkoski.github.io/Three.js/Video.html . However, I'd also like to use my site with the Google Cardboard Chrome API, as detailed here: https://vr.chromeexperiments.com/ , yet when I test the program on Chrome for Android, I get a 'S3TC textures not supported' error. Is there a way around this error?

Answer (score 0):

It's not an error, it just that S3TC is not supported. It's a file format error - like asking a program that only supports JPG to read an PNG.  You need to either convert the video to an accepted format, or perhaps see if there's a way of getting the Chrome API to turn on OpenGL extensions, the one you want is EXT_texture_compression_s3tc - if you can access this then you can read in S3TC files. S3TC is usually targeted on mobile devices - where file size is critical. If it's just for a web browser you might want to investigate useing a more standardized video format - like  H.264

You can also looks for a library that supports the formats you want to use and if they can uncode a frame, you can directly pass it to the graphics API.